# How to get a single character with sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to use `sscanf` to convert a single character from a string into its corresponding hex value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    char *str = "DEADBEEF";     
    int num;
    sscanf(str[2],"%x",&num);
    printf("%x",num);
}
```

When I try to compile, I get a warning because `sscanf` is looking for a `char *` rather than a single `char`. I could use the ampersand to get the address of the character (i.e. `&str[2]`) but that would read the rest of the string until it encounters a `\0`.

Comment: @lurker I'm trying to read a single character from the string and then read it as hexadecimal. In the example, I want to read ```A``` (the character at index 2) and convert it into an int with the value of ```0xA```

Comment: Then you want to use `&str[2]` since that's the address that holds the `A` (`sscanf` requires that *address* of the string you are reading), but then use something like `%1x` to read a single character as an integer instead of `%x` which is going to read as large an integer (in hex digits) as `sscanf` can read.

Comment: Use `if (sscanf(&str[2], "%1x", &num) != 1) { …oops… }`.  See [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved by [lurker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980550/lurker) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57641912/how-to-get-a-single-character-with-sscanf#comment101735619_57641912):

Using `sscanf(&str[2], "%1x", &num);` you can read a single character rather than as large of an integer as `sscanf` can read

Comment: You need `&num` not `num`. See @JonathanLeffler comment for the more complete solution with error checking.